# how to filter search result with dropdown list in php

Tags: java, php, search, filter

i am doing a webpage project. it have student role and teacher role. when teacher signed in their account, they are able to search students by name.

but many students can have the same name, i don't know how to code this part where when teacher typed student's name in the search bar, the result should filter all students' name. 
for example, teacher is searching for "john tan" then all the similar names should be displayed in the dropdownlist and filter all the results from the database."john tan mingjie" or "john lim"

thank you whoever is helping me with this!!!

Comment: To separate two persons with the same name "john tan": maybe add more information to the drop down (e.g. student id for separation, class or birth date, or maybe even a photo).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Select2 - a free jQuery plugin.

https://select2.github.io/examples.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
});

<select class="js-example-basic-single">
  <option value="1">James Raynor</option>
  <option value="2">Alexei Stukov</option>
    ...
  <option value="9999">Sarrah Kerrigan</option>
</select>
```

Easy as that :)

Comment: hi! i can't figure out. my whole page is having problems. am trying to solve it. but do you happen to know how i can save draft in database and retrieve it when i want? for example:student input reflection,they can choose to submit or save as draft. when they wish to edit, they can edit the draft then submit to teacher.

Comment: you can create a different table with the same structure and when he chooses to save to draft - insert into draft; when chooses to submit - insert into the real one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **LIKE** in the mysql command

```
    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM student_details WHERE student_name = :filter");
    $query->bindValue(":filter", $_REQUEST['name'] . "%");
    $query->execute();
```

I think this will help you.